# Set a html form with a input select, text and button horizontally

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to set a form horizontally, but by the moment each element is vertically I need it horizontally.

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
       <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:#cccccc; padding:5px;">
                <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
                            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                             <li class="breadcrumb-item"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> Candidates</li>
    
                            </ol>
                            
                        </nav>  
                </div>
            
            <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:white; padding:5px;">
              <nav class="navbar navbar-light float-left">
                  <form class="form-inline">
                  <select name="type" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                      <option>Search By:</option>
                      <option>names</option>
                      <option>phone</option>
                      <option>email</option>
                    </select>
                    
                    <input name="searchby" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="enter a value.." aria-label="Search">
                    
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                  </form>
                </nav>
            </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
```

Here is a picture:

[image]

I need something like this:

[image]

I have tried many ways but I got stuck, I also need to add another form below of it, also horizontally. I will appreciate any help. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the best practice to add a space between each element

You can make use of [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap) (grid-gap):

```css
.form-inline {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  gap: 1em;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <!-- CSS only -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:#cccccc; padding:5px;">
        <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
          <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> Candidates</li>

          </ol>

        </nav>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:white; padding:5px;">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light float-left">
          <form class="form-inline">
            <select name="type" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
              <option>Search By:</option>
              <option>names</option>
              <option>phone</option>
              <option>email</option>
            </select>

            <input name="searchby" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="enter a value.." aria-label="Search">

            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </nav>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

> But how I prevent a big size of separation when I add another form below

```css
form.form-inline{
margin-bottom: 0px;
padding-bottom:0px;
padding-top:none;
}
```

```html
 
<html>
 
<head>
  <!-- CSS only -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
 
<style type="text/css">
form.form-inline{
    display: inline-grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
    grid-column-gap: 10px;
    grid-row-gap:5px;
}
</style>
<body>
 
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:#cccccc; padding:5px;">
        <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
          <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> Candidates</li>
 
          </ol>
 
        </nav>
      </div>
 
      <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:white; padding:5px;">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light float-left">
          <form class="form-inline">
            <select name="type" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
              <option>Search By:</option>
              <option>names</option>
              <option>phone</option>
              <option>email</option>
            </select>
 
            <input name="searchby" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="enter a value.." aria-label="Search">
 
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </nav>
        
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light float-left">
          <form class="form-inline">
            <select name="type" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
              <option>Search By:</option>
              <option>names</option>
              <option>phone</option>
              <option>email</option>
            </select>
 
            <input name="searchby" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="enter a value.." aria-label="Search">
 
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </nav>
        
      </div>
 
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks bro it's very useful for me. But how I prevent a big size of separation when I add another form below like this: https://imgur.com/a/7WYW0TQ I have removed the nav tag but I need less space

Comment: @FreddyDaniel Can you provide the full code?

Comment: I'm using a template using laravel framework I just copy these piece of code that I have putted in my post.. Maybe the template is generating this big spaces or the same bootstrap.

Comment: @FreddyDaniel In that case, it would still be very helpful if you provided the output HTML (copied from the browser) *and* the CSS

Comment: Ok bro here is the code https://pastebin.com/urpKhrbr I just added another html form

Answer (score 1):

A little CSS adjustment to the form should align the inputs horizontally.

```css
form.form-inline{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

Another alternative is inline-grid, which gives more control of column size.

```css
form.form-inline{
    display: inline-grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
    grid-column-gap: 10px;
    grid-row-gap:5px;
}
```

Comment: Hi bro it works but what is the best practice to add a space between each element. https://imgur.com/a/UvGhQg1 And also I need  the input type text, with a width size more bigger , now looks tiny. Thanks

Comment: What should I do to prevent this big size when I added another form below https://imgur.com/a/TxqrGfY thanks.

Comment: @FreddyDaniel.
You can also utilize an inline-grid:
`form.form-inline{
    display: inline-grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
    grid-column-gap: 10px;
}`
This allows for easy control of column width and space between items.